# Bonita won't initiate a process after publishing

Tags: business-process-management, bonita

As the title says, I am unable to initiate my own process in bonita during development.

It works fine but after publishing and on initiating the new process, the submit button to new process does not go anywhere.

My understanding is that it should redirect me to the home-page and initiate the process... However, in this case, it's just not doing anything...

I am therefore unable to figure out whether it's an error or it has already initiated the process.

Comment: Can you open your web browser "developer tools" (usually using F12 key), go to network tab and then try again to submit the process instantiation form? You should see a HTTP POST request such as http://localhost:8080/bonita/portal/resource/process/Pool/1.0/API/bpm/process/6957049056752718529/instantiation Maybe it's currently failing because you didn't submit all the data expected by the process contract.

Comment: Actually, the problem was when I was appending the processDef[0].id to the URL, so it was not rendering it as a variable but as a string and so the link instead of localhost:8080/............/<a  bunch of numbers> was displayed as  localhost:8080/............/processDef[0].id and this link in console returns a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

here in UI Designer use

```
Process definition: {{processDef}} <br/><br/>
{{processDef[0].id}}
{{processDef[0].version}}
{{processDef[0].name}}
<br/><br/>
{{processDef[1].id}}
{{processDef[1].version}}
{{processDef[1].name}}
<br/><br/>
{{processDef[2].id}}
{{processDef[2].version}}
{{processDef[2].name}}
```

to know how many processes are there to run... and which process do you want to run.

Use this as a debug and assign that value in that process name.